# How suitable is "僧侶" for "priest"?

Tags: translation, religion

Page 79 of Fluent Forever's "Awesome Word List" for Japanese gives 僧侶 as the Japanese word for "priest", listed just after "教会" for "church". How suitable is it for "priest", if at all?

Doing a google image search for "僧侶" mainly gave Buddhists (though that could be because more Chinese-speakers and Japanese-speakers are Buddhists than Christians), the [English language Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%83%A7%E4%BE%B6#Japanese) translates it as Buddhist monks, while jisho.org says "priest; monk​ - Buddhist term" (seemingly saying that both "priest" and "monk" are Buddhist terms). The Japanese language's disambiguation page for [僧侶](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%83%A7%E4%BE%B6_(%E6%9B%96%E6%98%A7%E3%81%95%E5%9B%9E%E9%81%BF)) has mention of Christianity.

Comment: More general question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/55106/whats-the-difference-between-these-words-for-priest?s=2|42.5903

Comment: たま～にですけど、キリスト教の教会の聖職者のことを「僧侶」って言うの聞きますね・・

Answer (score 6, accepted):

僧侶 (僧) is sometimes used as a catch-all term for priests and monks of non-Asian religions. This is typically true for imaginary religions in fiction. For example [priests/僧侶 in *Dragon Quest* franchise](http://dragonquest.wikia.com/wiki/Priest) do not look like that of Buddhism at all.

僧侶 is rare for Christian clergies because Christianity has the set of better-known terms like 修道士.

Comment: FWIW, as a Christian, I have never seen 修道士 used anywhere.  I'm seeing it translated as "monk" or "friar", which feel very antiquated.

Comment: @istrasci I'm wondering if there's a better gender-neutral English term for "nun/sister". For example how do you call [these people](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:BenedictineVespers.jpg) if "monk" is not the right word?